# Is there any way to use $_POST instead of $_GET?

Tags: php

**PROBLEM:**
I have the following code to write so customers can write their own news post. This code uses $_GET to receive the text written by the customer. When the customer writes a big post, the URL gets too long and the webpage refuses to submit it to the "write" page posted below.

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$content = $_GET['content'];

$file_handle = fopen("../userdata/" . $username . ".news.js", "w");
$file_contents = "document.write('<div style=\'font-size:17px;\'>" . $title . "</div><hr /><div style=\'font-size:12px;margin-bottom:20px;font-style:italic;\'>Posted on " . date("d/m/Y") . "</div><div style=\'font-size:14px;\'>" . $content . "</div>');";

fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Like you can see, the code uses $_GET. Is there any way to make it $_POST so it doesn't submit through $_GET?

Comment: change all instances of GET to POST?

Comment: so use POST instead?

Comment: the submission is being sent from the web page, right?.  change your form method to "post"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method  and change your code to use $_POST (or $_REQUEST)

Comment: that's what I meant by all of the above ^ (*all instances of...*) ;-)

Comment: I tried it before but it didnt work but now it works when using request, thanks brus

Comment: was just going to say that ^ to use `$_REQUEST` - *"Follow your instincts Fred"*

Comment: @CarlJohnson `$_REQUEST` is a good one to use in this case, as it will work with both GET and POST data.  see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 2):

Why do you usw $_GET ? Use  $_POST instead, and change the HTML-attribute in the input-form from `method="get"` to `method="post"`.